# Assessment Calculator in Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, formula, syntax, design-patterns

I need to build an assessment calculator that will perform the following:

POINTS: 0.0 - 3.0

COST: $0.00 - $1000

ASSESSMENT RATING: LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH

Assessment logic:

If POINTS between 0.0 and 1.0, and COST between $0.00 and $350, then ASSESMENT RATING = LOW

If POINTS between 1.0 and 2.0, and COST between $350 and $700, then ASSESSMENT RATING = MEDIUM

If POINTS between 2.0 and 3.0, and COST between $700 and $1000, then ASSESSMENT RATING = HIGH

Alt;

If POINTS between 0.00 and 1.0, and COST between $700 and $1000, then ASSESSMENT RATING = MEDIUM

If POINTS between 1.0 and 2.0, and COST between $0.00 and $350, then ASSESSMENT RATING = LOW

The idea is to determine ASSESSMENT RATING based on the range of POINTS and COST - a simple assessment calculator.

The challenge is to do this in Power Apps, listing a stack of custom conditions / permutations in a way that is readable and viable.

*An optional feature could be an addition of weighing values (referenced from a SharePoint list) on POINTS, in group categories that can be changed by owners if / when required.
**The same could be applied on COST in the form of percentage discount (referenced from a SharePoint list).

This would amount to a resourceful pattern for many solutions.

What is the best way to achieve this in Power Apps?

(The actual syntax required to articulate the list of assessment conditions to get consistent / reliable rating results).

Answer (score 1):

The logic would be a lot easier to achieve in a SharePoint list - using Calculated column.
Although I do not recommend writing the logic all in PowerApps since it increases the loading time tremendously, it is workable. *ASSESSMENT RATING* field should be Read-Only either way.

Assuming you have this PowerApps form attached to a SharePoint list, column value ranges can be easily configured via Column settings.

Add a Label to the form to display the value for *ASSESSMENT RATING* (Note that the value cannot be passed back to the list). Here is a sample formula based on the provided logic:

```
POINTS = DataCardValue2
COST = DataCardValue3

If((((Value(DataCardValue2.Text)>0.0)&&(Value(DataCardValue2.Text)<1.0))||((Value(DataCardValue2.Text)>1.0)&&(Value(DataCardValue2.Text)<2.0))&&(Value(DataCardValue3.Text)>0.00)&&(Value(DataCardValue3.Text)<350)),"LOW",
    If((((Value(DataCardValue2.Text)>1.0)&&(Value(DataCardValue2.Text)<2.0)&&(Value(DataCardValue3.Text)>350)&&(Value(DataCardValue3.Text)<700))||((Value(DataCardValue2.Text)>0.0)&&(Value(DataCardValue2.Text)<1.0)&&(Value(DataCardValue3.Text)>700)&&(Value(DataCardValue3.Text)<1000))),"MEDIUM",
        If((Value(DataCardValue2.Text)>2.0)&&(Value(DataCardValue2.Text)<3.0)&&(Value(DataCardValue3.Text)>700)&&(Value(DataCardValue3.Text)<1000),"HIGH")
    )
)
```

[image]